# Time Range in SQL Server only for date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Named `Transactions` and it holds data like this :

```
transaction_id   cust_id   tran_date  
 80712190438     270351     28-02-14
 29258453508     270384     27-02-14
 58387181112     275068     31-12-13
 21300411973     274568     31-12-13
 26229626485     267624     31-12-12
 26229126485     267634     31-12-12
 47557596721     273764     31-12-11
 28966519600     273899     31-12-11
```

Now, what is the Time Range of the Transaction Data available for analysis?

and 2nd part of the Question is:

Show the Output in the `number of Days`, `Months` and `Years` simultaneously.

Both of these should be done in Single Query.

I used Query below to get the days, months and years but I'm stuck to find time range.

```
  SELECT 
    MIN(CAST(CAST(tran_date AS NCHAR(8)) AS date)) AS Start_tran_Date
    ,MAX(CAST(CAST(tran_date AS NCHAR(8)) AS date)) AS End_tran_Date
    ,DATEDIFF(DAY,MAX(CAST(CAST(tran_date AS NCHAR(8)) AS date)), MIN(CAST(CAST(tran_date AS NCHAR(8)) AS date)) ) AS Difference_Days
    ,DATEDIFF(MONTH,MAX(CAST(CAST(tran_date AS NCHAR(8)) AS date)), MIN(CAST(CAST(tran_date AS NCHAR(8)) AS date)) ) AS Difference_Months
    ,DATEDIFF(YEAR,MAX(CAST(CAST(tran_date AS NCHAR(8)) AS date)), MIN(CAST(CAST(tran_date AS NCHAR(8)) AS date)) ) AS Difference_Years
FROM Transactions
```

But it gives me this error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 50 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

I want output in

```
tran_date_start  tran_date_end  No.of Days  No.of Months  No.of Years
```

Comment: You didn't need to use `datepart` because you are not being asked for components of date, but for a length of a time range. The time range in the data you've shown is "from 31-12-11 to 28-02-14". Now determine how many days, months and years that is.

Comment: I dont see any dates in your data, only strings that look like dates e.g. `31-12-13`.

Comment: Please show us your attempt

Comment: What results do you want?

Answer (score 1):

You date format is `dd-mm-yy`, So if you `CAST` like below.

```
SELECT CAST('28-02-14' AS DATE)
```

It's incorrect, That is the reason why you get error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

You should use `Convert` instead, looks like this

```
SELECT Convert(DATE,'28-02-14',3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bulding on Anoymous' answer you can use a sub-query to make the code much clearer -- like this:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(trans_dt) AS Start_tran_Date,
    MAX(trans_dt) AS End_tran_Date,
    DATEDIFF(DAY,  MAX(trans_dt), MIN(trans_dt) ) AS Difference_Days,
    DATEDIFF(MONTH,MAX(trans_dt), MIN(trans_dt) ) AS Difference_Months,
    DATEDIFF(YEAR, MAX(trans_dt), MIN(trans_dt) ) AS Difference_Years
FROM (
  SELECT transaction_id,   cust_id,  CONVERT(date,tran_date,3) as tran_dt
  FROM Transaction
)
```

Answer (score 0):

** EDITED

As you are storing dates as VARCHAR, which is not recommended (always format dates as dates) you need to cast the values to NCHAR and afterwards to dates to make the calculation work.

If you only need the the difference in days, you can use `DATEDIFF` function, where you find the difference between two dates. By taking the difference `MIN(date)` and `MAX(date)` in the you data, you will get the amount of days between those two dates.

```
SELECT 
    MIN(CAST(CAST(trans_date AS NCHAR(8)) AS date)) AS Start_tran_Date
    ,MAX(CAST(CAST(trans_date AS NCHAR(8)) AS date)) AS End_tran_Date
    ,DATEDIFF(DAY,MAX(CAST(CAST(trans_date AS NCHAR(8)) AS date)), MIN(CAST(CAST(trans_date AS NCHAR(8)) AS date)) ) AS Difference_Days
    ,DATEDIFF(MONTH,MAX(CAST(CAST(trans_date AS NCHAR(8)) AS date)), MIN(CAST(CAST(trans_date AS NCHAR(8)) AS date)) ) AS Difference_Months
    ,DATEDIFF(YEAR,MAX(CAST(CAST(trans_date AS NCHAR(8)) AS date)), MIN(CAST(CAST(trans_date AS NCHAR(8)) AS date)) ) AS Difference_Years
FROM Transactions
```

This will give you the following output:

```
Start_tran_Date   End_tran_Date   Difference_Days   Difference_Months  Difference_Years 
2011-12-31        2014-02-28      790               26                 3
```

Comment: Thanks @Atmira,   but using your query gave me this error:    Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 42
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Actually, the data types are in VARCHAR().

Comment: @MOHDMUQEEMNASIR Correction has been made

Comment: sorry to disturbing you @Atmira...... but still I'm getting the same error:    Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 42
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer,

```
Select Datediff(day,Min((CONVERT(date, tran_date, 103))),Max(CONVERT(date, tran_date, 103))) as days,
Datediff(month,Min((CONVERT(date, tran_date, 103))),Max(CONVERT(date, tran_date, 103))) as months,
Datediff(year,Min((CONVERT(date, tran_date, 103))),Max(CONVERT(date, tran_date, 103))) as year
 from [dbo].[Transactions]
```